# Set limitation on inserting edittext length in java code

Tags: android

I want to create an edittext that has a limitation on input length. When the edittext length is more than five it should display an error toast message. The app compiles but it crashes in the emulator and does not open. My code is below, any help would be appreciated.

```
<EditText
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="50dp"
  android:id="@+id/etext1"
  />



    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="B1"
    android:id="@+id/one"
    android:text="1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/etext1"
    android:gravity="center"

    />
```

The Java code looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

EditText tx=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etext1);
String a;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }



     public void B1(View v) {

         if (tx.getText().toString().length()>5)

         {


             LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

             View erro = inflater.inflate(R.layout.error, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.idoferror));


             Toast dis = Toast.makeText(this, "er", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
             dis.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.RIGHT, 0, 0);
             dis.setView(erro);
             dis.show();


         }

         else {

             a=tx.getText().toString();
             a=a+1;
             tx.setText(a);




         }

     }
```

}

Comment: android:maxLength="15"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move this

```
EditText tx=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etext1);
```

line in `onCreate()` And set `android:maxLength="5"`

### Edit

```
EditText tx;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tx=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.etext1);
  }
```

Comment: hi tkhanks but when i move the edittextlin on  onCreate ,inside the onlclick method the edittext can not be recognized

Comment: hi sorry just look carefully just works fine thanksss

Answer (score 0):

To show the `Toast` when you reach the limit characters. You need to add `TextWatcher` to your `EditText`.
After each time you enter the text to your `EditText`, check the length of your `EditText` then show the `Toast` and `setText()` again for your `EditText` if needed

```
final int MAX_CHARACTERS = 5;
...
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        if (yourEditText.toString().length() > MAX_CHARACTERS) {
            yourEditText.setText(yourEditText.getText().toString().substring(0, MAX_CHARACTERS));
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Maximum number of characters reached.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
});
```

===
IF you just only want to limit the text length not show the `Toast`. You can use

```
yourEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(MAX_CHARACTERS)});
```

or in XML

```
android:maxLength="5"
```

Hope this help